# How can I fix my 1st gen iPad if I can't restore (error 3194) and have forgotten the password?

Tags: ipad, restore

I googled to try to solve this, but changing the hostfile didn't work and using tinyumbrella didn't work either. I'm still getting the same error 3194.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by deleting `private/etc/hosts` and rebooting my computer.

Comment: You generally don't want to entirely delete your hosts file - instead, edit it and remove any lines mentioning `gs.apple.com`.